# Notifications on past voted questions/answers?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Is it possible to setup automatic notifications when someone answers a question on questions or answers that you have ***voted*** on in the past?

Sometimes, I want to see what answers come up in the future on answers or questions I voted on.

Comment: I think this is what "favourite" option is for.

Comment: This is what the favorite option _should_ be for imo, but it's not. As far as I know there is no way to get notifications on question updates unless you posted the question.

Comment: There probably something on stackapps

Comment: I just discovered that there's a feed for every question on the bottom of the page - [this is the feed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/10838) for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible using the functionality provided by SE. The best you can do is manually check the [favorites tab in your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114274/299342) to check if any of your favorite questions have received new answers since you last visited the tab. I agree that it would be nice to receive a notification in my inbox when certain questions receive a new answer or a post is edited, though I would want this to be an opt-in feature (on a per post basis) so that I don't receive too many notifications.

Although this feature is not provided by SE, you may be interested in a feature provided by the [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX) userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/39698); one of [its features](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/wiki/Features) allows you to mark a post so that you are notified when it is edited. The feature was inspired by the MSE post [Allow me to get notifications on specific down-voted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165962/299342), though it's not limited to questions that were downvoted:

> You don't actually have to use this in conjunction with downvotes -- use it as an alternative 'favourite' feature for notifications on any edits
>
> <sub>[ᔕᖺᘎᕊ's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276840/299342)</sub>

Comment: Does SE have to have this feature? Can it not be made just for SciFi SE? Cheers.

Comment: As a user of SOX, I can say it is very useful

Comment: Got SOX installed and I am happy now.

Comment: Thanks you very much for SOX!

Answer (score 3):

### Nope.

This isn't possible with current SE functionality. Related feature requests on main meta:

- [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: "I think I've fixed the issue now - please check"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/278659) from 2009 - marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined);
- [Should you be notified if something you vote on is edited? Why can you change your vote after something's been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135626/278659) from 2012 - slightly more general, still never implemented;
- [Subscribing to questions and comments that don't belong to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45360/278659) from 2010 - this *was* actually implemented for a while, but then pulled in 2012 (see the answers);
- [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343/278659) from 2011 - a proposal from an SE employee, and probably currently your best hope of getting anything like this implemented.